# PyCharm: download from remote host?

Tags: deployment, configuration, host, pycharm

I have deployment options set up correctly and uploading works without issues, I can upload individual files as well as the whole project.

But in the Remote Host panel the download/upload buttons are grayed out, if individual files are selected, and only active when the root path is selected. Hitting "Download from here" does nothing except showing "Download from " status in the "File Transfer " window.

PyCharm docs state that downloads will only work if the deployment configuration has been appointed as default. But it *is* default (and only) configuration.

Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Comment: There is still no solution to this very trivial but vital ask. - 2022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known limitation](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-1398) of the remote hosts support plug-in. Feel free to vote.

Comment: Thanks, just did. I see it's pretty high on your priority list. Any idea when it will be implemented?

Comment: Most likely in PyCharm 2.x, beginning of the next year.